# Hot reloading python process for code reload

Tags: python, python-3.x, sanic

Any way to hot reload python modules for a running python process? In usual cases we could run `kill -HUP <pid>` for some of the servers like squid, nginx,gunicorn. My running processes are

```
root 6  0.6  0.9 178404 39116 ?  S    14:21   0:00 python3 ./src/app.py --config ./conf/config.yml
root 7  0.0  1.0 501552 43404 ?  Sl   14:21   0:00 python3 ./src/app.py --config ./conf/config.yml
root 8  0.0  1.0 501808 43540 ?  Sl   14:21   0:00 python3 ./src/app.py --config ./conf/config.yml
```

Comment: Any such reloading would require support from the program in question—are you asking how to *implement* such support?

Comment: I am more inclined to know if the cpython runtime has any hidden options. on some of the frameworks, there are some option that I know. For eg flask has auto reload option

Comment: Possible solutions depend on what do you mean under _hot reload_, can you elaborate that? Do you want this feature in a dev environment or for production-running apps?

Answer (score 1):

Is the question about reloading a Sanic app? If yes, then there is a hot reload built into the server.

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Or if you want the reload without debugging

```
app.run(auto_reload=True)
```

[See docs](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/debug_mode.html)

Or, if this is a question in general, checkout [aoiklivereload](https://github.com/AoiKuiyuyou/AoikLiveReload)